# Redis lrange OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, redis, out-of-memory, jedis

```
 Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
        long len = jedis.llen(table);
        List<String> tableKeys = jedis.lrange(table, (long) 0, len);
        for (String key : tableKeys) {
            pipeline.del(key);
            pipeline.lrem(table, 1, key);
        }
        pipeline.sync();
        tableKeys.clear();
```

I am running into a issue here, when the key set is large I am getting an out of memory error at jedis.llrange.

Is there a better way to handle this, may be run the lrange in batches or pipelining the lrange?

I am planning on using a LUA script, just wanted to know if this would work

```
local result = redis.call('lrange',KEYS[1],0,ARGV[1]-1)
for i,k in ipairs(result) do
    redis.call(‘del’,k)
    redis.call('ltrim',KEYS[1],1,k)
end
```

Comment: You will need to perform chunked processing (for(int i=0;i<len;i+=100) {...}). Jedis has no streaming API, so you're required to build it by yourself. You could create also a Lua script that performs the actions for you or the last option, use a client that allows you to stream.

Comment: the LUA script works well for now will try and test more cases